# php json формат

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте сделал скрипт, для упрощения работы с json, но появляются лишние скобки.
Код :

```
$data = $_GET['json'];
$new_array = [];
if($data != null){
    $array = json_decode($data, true);
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        
        if($key == "approveNumber" or $key == 'hiddenReferences' or $key == 'title') continue;
        $block[] = [
            $key=> ["html" => "t.$key"]
        ];


    }
    print_r(json_encode($block, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот эти скобки надо убрать (я их на скриншоте зачеркнул)

Как это можно реализовать ? не лезит в бошку :)

Comment: Если ответ помог- отметьте его галочкой слева от текста ответа

Comment: См:[Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$data = $_GET['json'];
$new_array = [];
if($data != null){
    $array = json_decode($data, true);
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        
        if($key == "approveNumber" or $key == 'hiddenReferences' or $key == 'title') continue;
        $block[$key]["html"] ="t.$key";
    }
    print_r(json_encode($block, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
}
```

Спасибо @u_mulder за замечание! <3